# Nexmo Laravel connect to PSTN endpoint not working

Tags: laravel, vonage

My code is shown below. Everything works for me, besides connecting a call to a PSTN endpoint. I'm thinking possibly that maybe the "connect" functions aren't included in the Laravel Nexmo packages that I'm using. I'm using these:

https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-laravel

Which is built on another nexmo package:

https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-php

My code:

```php
public function getNexmoAnswer(Request $request)
{
    return
            [
        [
            'action' => 'talk',
            'voiceName' => 'Justin',
            'text' => 'Welcome to our great site’
        ],
        [
            'action' => 'talk',
            'voiceName' => 'Justin',

            'text' => "Press # to search now the e.t.a status of your latest order.",
            'bargeIn' => true
        ],
        [
            'action' => 'connect',
            'from' => '17181234567’,
            'endpoint' => [
            'type' => 'phone',
            'number' => '18451234567’
                          ]
        ]
             ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The connect action is part of Nexmo's NCCO system and is unrelated to Nexmo-Laravel and Nexmo-PHP. Your NCCO looks to be correct to me.

To connect to another number, you'll need to have activated your account by adding credit. In addition, the `from` number you're using (`17181234567`) must be a number purchased from Nexmo

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm stumped as to why it's not working. It's working fine with the exact same numbers and code in the playground provided by Nexmo on their site. But alas! not in my app - which made me think I'm off with a comma or a bracket etc. in Laravel.